# Displaying conditional html with Knockout

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, coffeescript

I have an knockout observable array of activities which contains audits and comments.  I've got the data from the server and sorted the array of activities based on the timestamp of the objects.

I'd like to be able to conditionally display html based on the type, so audits and comments will look different.

```
<!-- ko foreach: activities -->
<div class="audit" data-bind="visible: {activity is typeof Audit}"> 
    @*Do some audit html*@
</div>
<div class="comment" data-bind="visible: {activity is typeof Comment}"> 
    @*Do some comment html*@
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

I've got the following html but I don't know how do the condition, I just wrote something in above as a placeholder so you get the idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

I'm probably approaching this all wrong, any help much appreciated!

Comment: I think `data-bind="visible: {activity.hasOwnProperty(<SOME UNIQUE FOR AUDIT PPOPERTY NAME HERE>)}"` will work but could you please provide a JS fiddle for testing?

Comment: I've never used js fiddle before but I'll try and get one going and then add as an edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nayjest's solution should work if you change the visible binding to an if binding - that way it won't try render the parts with the title dependency.

A better solution, however, is probably to have two templates and execute them based on the type. You could have a method on the VM that takes $data and returns, for example, 'auditTemplate' or 'commentTemplate' depending on the result of something like $data instanceof Audit. You would then have two templates embedded as script tags with those ids:

```
<script id="auditTemplate" type="text/html">
<div class="audit">
<!-- Do some audit stuff -->
</div>
</script>

<script id="commentTemplate" type="text/html">
<div class="comment">
<!-- Do some comment stuff -->
</div>
</script>
```

And then in your VM, you'd have something like:

```
this.getTemplate = function(data) {
return (data instanceof Audit) ? 'auditTemplate' : 'commentTemplate'
}
```

In your page's html you'd do something like:

```
<!-- ko foreach: activities -->
<div databind="template: {name:$parent.getTemplate($data), data: $data}"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have class Audit that is visible in global scope and property 'activities' of view model, try something like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: activities">
   <div data-bind="visible: $data instanceof Audit">
       <h1 data-bind="text: $data.title"></h1>
       <!-- Some other data here -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, this works nicely but unfortunately it still parses the inner elements.  So if it's a comment it still tries to run $data.title but falls over because comment has no title property.  I'm being steered towards using templates.

Comment: Maybe consider using the if-binding instead of the visible-binding: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html - that way, the inner bindings don't get applied until the condition is true.